# Question about fixed data and the memory marshal (C#)

Tags: c#, pointers, fixed, low-level

I have a question about the two following pieces of code. I want to know if the would work the same way.

```cs
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
public ulong[] ID;
```

and

```cs
public fixed ulong ID[4];
```

Haven't tried any solutions, unsure of what to expect.
Thanks all in advance.